# How to Subscription details from the wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order() function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this variable:

```
$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order($order_id, array('order_type' => 'parent'));
```

Using this print_r() I can see lots of data:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($subscriptions);
echo '</pre>';
```

How can I get some specific data like when the next payment date, when a user purchased the product, which product etc?

Is there any way?

Comment: $subscriptions->get_date_completed() , $subscriptions->get_items(), $subscriptions->get_status() ....

Comment: Thank you very much. can you give me some reference for other funcitons?

Comment: its not showing anything. Can you check please?

Answer (score 0):

`$subscriptions-> get_date_created() , $subscriptions->get_items(), $subscriptions->get_status()` `$subscription->get_date( 'next_payment' )`
Subscription is extended from WC_Order class. All the functions available for the order object are also available for the subscription object

https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/

Comment: but using print_r() I can see the data but why `echo $subscriptions->get_date_completed();` is not showing anything

Comment: I have the order id now I want to get the order details. like next payment date, who made it, how much amount, etc.

Comment: but the code I have applied from you is not showing nothing.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/DZ6DAk this is the output of `$subscription_obj`

Comment: get_customer_I'd(), get_date_created(), get _total()